# Return all words which have their reverse present in a string

Tags: c++, strings, hash-map

**Problem Statement:**

> Given a string of words return all words which have their reverse present in the string as ( (word1 , reverseword1 ) , (word2 ,reverseword2) )

Example Case:

Input:

> Sachin tendulkar is the best tseb eht nihcaS

Output:

> { ( best ,   tseb )  , ( the  ,  eht) , (Sachin  ,  nihcaS) }

My approach is to use a map and return the words if a match to the reverse of the current word is found in the map.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
unordered_map <string, int> binMap;
string test="Sachin tendulkar is the best tseb eht nihcaS si";
int i=0,j=0;
string temp,rev;
string::iterator it;
cout<<"{";

for(i = 0, it = test.begin() ; it <= test.end(); ++it)
    {   

        if(*it==' ' || it==test.end())
        {   
            temp=test.substr(j,i-j);
            rev=string(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend());
            if(binMap[rev]==1)
            cout<<"( "<<rev<<","<<temp<<" ), ";
            else
            binMap[temp]=1;
            j=i+1;
        }
        i++;
    }
cout<<"}";
return 0;
}
```

Is this the most optimal way to solve the problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Interesting concept of the classic reversal problem! Good question and welcome to Code Review :)

Comment: Is this the actual problem statement?  If so, I would expect to see substring matching.  E.g. `"This si"` should produce `{(si,is)}` as `"is"` is present in the string `"This si"`.

Comment: @Snowhawk04 The problem specifically says words. So, I dont think it applies to substrings as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have observed a few things that may help you improve your code.

### Use library functions

One of the things the code does is to separate words in the input.  However, this could be done more easily by using a `std::stringstream`:

```
stringstream in(test);
string word;
while (in >> word) {
    // test each word
}
```

### Use more whitespace to enhance readability of the code

Instead of crowding things together like this:

```
cout<<"( "<<rev<<","<<temp<<" ), ";
```

most people find it more easily readable if you use more space:

```
cout << "( " << rev << ", " << word << " ) ";
```

### Only print words once

Right now, with this input string:

```
string test="Sachin tendulkar is si is the best tseb eht nihcaS si";
```

The word "is" gets reported twice.

> {( is,si ), ( best,tseb ), ( the,eht ), ( Sachin,nihcaS ), ( is,si ), }

One way to handle that is to note when each word is actually reported and to only do it once.  Here's one way to do that:

```
stringstream in(test);
enum state { DETECTED=1, REPORTED };
unordered_map <string, state> binMap;

string word;
cout << "{";
while (in >> word) {
    string rev{word.rbegin(), word.rend()};
    if (binMap[rev] == DETECTED && binMap[word] != REPORTED) {
        cout << "( " << rev << ", " << word << " ) ";
        binMap[word] = REPORTED;
    } else {
        binMap[word] = DETECTED;
    }
}
cout << "}\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several choosing style issues that make this hard to read and understand:

- The variables i and j would be so much better as wordEnd and wordStart
- The indentation is lacking inside the innermost if statement, and inconsistent and weird throughout
- Many of the variables should have been declared inside the for statement to minimize their scope
- using namespace std is considered bad practice

This program would be a lot easier to play with and to test if it took the test string as a command line argument.

I suppose you called binMap that way because it will only contain 0 or 1 as values. In that case int is the wrong value type. Boolean wouldn't be the right type either, because a map with binary values could probably be a set. You could have used the int as a counter to avoid printing the same values twice. But even so, only a few int values would be used. So the best solution is what Edward proposed.